# Why are default select's options unaffected by overflow: hidden?

Tags: html, css

For starters, check this fiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/xV4s3/

As you can see, we have a wrapper with `overflow: hidden` and inside there is a native `select` with three options and an `ul` styled to look like a select with three items.
 Now, when you click on the ul,  you can see its height changes (due to the script), but nothing beyond the wrapper is seen, because of the `overflow: hidden`. And that works as expected.
My question is about the default `select`'s options, since I couldn't find anything in the specifications.
 Why are they not affected by `overflow: hidden` ?

Comment: Possibly because the drop-down menu isn't created as a descendant of the wrapper, or even the `select` element.

Comment: I was wondering something similar - is the `select`'s menu considered an HTML element at all, but still, you can apply some styles to the `option` elements which affect that menu, which makes it weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably nothing more than an implementation detail. The only thing CSS2.1 says about [overflow control](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html) is that the `overflow` property controls overflowing of content according to the containing block to which the property is applied. It does not define the behavior and rendering of form elements and such with respect to this property.

As I commented, it's clear that the drop-down menu isn't being created as a descendant of the wrapper, or even the `select` element. In fact, it's possible that most browsers choose to render it completely independently of the canvas and as an application-level or system-level UI element in its own right (likely for usability reasons). Note that while you can apply CSS to the `option` elements to influence the way the drop-down menu displays, you cannot actually style the drop-down menu itself.

Comment: Makes sense. :) At first I thought the menu is actually a descendant in some way, which it seems isn't and it just depends on the browser's methods of rendering it. Thank you for taking time to answer that.